# Плагин сортировки для JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, сортировка

Есть для jquery плагин выполняющий сортировку элементов, и сохранение результата в БД. [Здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=998) и демка есть. Как можно ее изменить, чтобы не делать по 30-40 и более запросов за раз?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вас не устраивает именно большое количество запросов на обновление. Вот эта часть:

```
foreach ($array as $idval) {
        $query = "UPDATE dragdrop SET listorder = " . $count . " WHERE id = " . $idval;
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $count ++;
    }
```

может быть заменена одним sql запросом

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1=CASE WHEN id=1 then 1,
                         WHEN id=2 then 0,
                         when id=3 then 1 END  WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

написать хранимую процедуру и вызывать ее, передавая только параметры

Comment: Я незнаю как((

Comment: Я только предположил, возможно там нестоит этого делать или вообще не надо, чем тебя вариант примера не устраивает? Почитай сначала основы sql, а то сразу такие вопросы ставишь неподготовившись)

Answer (score 0):

ну можно например сохранять только изменившиеся позиции. Например, есть таблица table:

```
ID             |             NAME
1                            NAME1
2                            NAME2
3                            NAME3
4                            NAME4
5                            NAME5
```

где ID - PRIMARY KEY.
Например, поменялись местами пункты 3 и 5. Делаем 3 простых запроса:

```
UPDATE `table`.`ID` SET `ID` = '0' WHERE `table`.`ID` = 3;
UPDATE `table`.`ID` SET `ID` = '3' WHERE `table`.`ID` = 5;
UPDATE `table`.`ID` SET `ID` = '5' WHERE `table`.`ID` = 0;
```

и получаем  то что нам нужно.

Comment: Плагин не меняет местами 2 элемента.. Если поменять местами 3 и 5 пункты, то будет затронут еще и 4 пункт. 

Допустим есть 20 элементов отсортированных по порядку от 1 до 20. Берем 15 элемент и перенесем на место 7 элемента. Теперь 7 станет на месте 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 10 -> 11 и т.д.. Вобщем свой порядок изменят все элементы с 7 до 15

Comment: Ну так можно же менять местами до тех пор пока все в нужном порядке не выстроится. 
Например, было:
8 9 10 11
Хотим, чтоб стало:
9 11 10 8

Меняем: 8->9, 8->10, 8 -> 11
Но здесь опять же выигрываем по времени только в случае больших списков и малых изменениях. Именно для такого случая я и делал так. Т.е. есть например список из 10000 элементов а изменились позиции только у элементов с номерами от 5430 до 5440. Вместо 10000 запросов получаем 30.